# PHP on Mac OS not recognizing <?=...?> syntax

Tags: php, macos

I have some PHP files developed on a Linux machine, which I am now working on on a Mac (OS 10.8.2). Pages were not showing up correctly on the Mac, even when they were showing correctly on the linux box. After some investigation, I found that it was because it wasn't recognizing syntax like this:

```
<?=$var ?>
```

Anything starting with just a `<?`, rather than a `<?php` (not just the var shortcut above, any block of code) is being interpreted as plain text, rather than PHP. On the Linux dev box and production server, the shortcut `<?` syntax is recognized just fine. I assume this is a configuration thing that I missed during setup, so what did I miss? Can I configure my Mac to recognize this syntax?

The mac is running `PHP 5.3.15`. The dev box is running an earlier `5.*`. I don't know the version on the production server.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These are called short tags.

Edit your `php.ini` file and set:

```
short_open_tag=On
```

Answer (score 8):

Either upgrade to PHP 5.4 (which supports `<?= .. ?>` all the time), or enable the "short tags" setting in the `php.ini` file.